# How can I use python (BOTO3) to cycle through all AWS EC2 instances and remove a security group from them?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I am looking for a script that will cycle through all of my AWS EC2 instances, check for a specific security group, and then delete that group from the instance.

I've been reading through the documentation here: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.delete_security_group but I'm not sure how I can apply that to a for loop within Python or Bash.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong class, you want modify_instance_attribute instead of delete_security_group. Delete_security_group will remove the sq from your account if it worked, but it would fail if there are things using the security group. Look at this instead, focus on the Groups section:

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_instance_attribute

Here is a quick and dirty example, I whipped up to show how to loop through it and set all this instances to the default security group. Hopefully you can take it from here. Good luck

```
import boto3

boto3.setup_default_session(region_name='us-west-2')
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
paginator = ec2.get_paginator('describe_instances')
instances = paginator.paginate().build_full_result()

instance_list = []
try:
    for reservation in instances['Reservations']:
        for instance in reservation['Instances']:
            instance_list.append(instance['InstanceId'])

    for i in image['Images']:
        client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=image, Groups=['Default',])

except Exception as e:
    print e
```